# a better way to express "an idea/thought suddenly came to me"

Tags: expressions

What are some grandiloquent, or simply better, ways of expressing "an idea/thought suddenly came to me", or "an idea/thought struck me", or "I was struck by an idea/thought"?

Comment: Your 3 examples are all cases where 'me' is passive, being acted on by 'an idea/thought'.  Is that your context?  You want examples of other things ideas can do to a passive you?

Comment: Related: [What is the name of the moment when the detective solves the mystery or realizes who the murderer is?](http://english.stackexchange.com/q/84135/8732), [Word for seeing someone’s moment of realization?](http://english.stackexchange.com/q/91208/8732), [Word for a rare feeling](http://english.stackexchange.com/q/70965/8732), [Brainstorm](http://english.stackexchange.com/q/77248/8732), [Metaphor for an important discovery](http://english.stackexchange.com/q/115560/8732), [Substitute for “The thought came to my mind”](http://english.stackexchange.com/q/87794/8732)

Comment: ***Eureka!*** says it all.

Comment: Grandiloquent: *pompous or extravagant in language, style, or manner, especially in a way that is intended to impress*. Do you really want to sound pompous?

Comment: @user53578878979080099421313131, Why not Eureka?

Comment: Needs some background effort to show.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I had an epiphany.

(a moment of sudden and great revelation or realization)

Comment: Why not Eureka?

Answer (score 9):

An "Aha!" moment.

Or, "I had a sudden insight."

Or, "It finally dawned on me!"

Or, "I experienced a paradigm shift."

Or, "Suddenly, all the pieces fit together in one moment of inspiration!"

Or, "A revelatory moment."

Or, "An intuitive perception."

Or, "A mental breakthrough."

Or, "A eureka moment."

Answer (score 5):

If you are writing primarily for everyday communication (e.g. email or chat), then always find the simplest language, while still being professional. In this case, you can simply say something like:

> It just hit me, ...
>
> It just struck me, ...

If you are writing longer form and want to be more expressive/stylistic, many of the answers above are great.

Answer (score 4):

An idea just **popped into my head**. From [Cambridge Dictionaries](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/pop-something-in-into-something):

> Something that pops into your head/mind is an idea that you suddenly have
>   (*He jotted down story ideas that popped into his head.*)

Comment: This has the potential for a good answer. If, and only if, you explain why it is a good expression. Please add some objective source and an explanation. Have a look at the [help center](http://english.stackexchange.com/help) to find out about good answers.

Answer (score 3):

[***brainwave*** (ODO)](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/brainwave)

*NOUN*

**2** [USUALLY IN SINGULAR] *informal* A sudden clever idea:
then he had a brainwave

More example sentences

> I was fingering my car keys, wondering if my perverse appetite would
> last all the way to Tesco's and back, when I had a sudden brainwave.
>
> Anyway, as she went on and got more and more into it, I had a sudden
> brainwave.
>
> Those words hit Rick like stones, a brainwave and an idea
> quickly ensued.

Answer (score 1):

**A light bulb moment**
[TFD](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/light+bulb+moment)

> Informal a moment of sudden inspiration, revelation, or recognition
>   [from the cartoon image of a light bulb lighting up above a character's head when he or she has an idea]

Related to the concept of light providing an answer, is the noun

**illumination**  *"In a moment of illumination"* 
[TFD](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/illumination)

> 1. spiritual or intellectual enlightenment; insight or understanding